# Question about how to calculate the Autocorrelation

Tags: correlation

There are at least two possibilities available on how to calculate the Autocorrelation of a one-dimensional data set.

1. Using `CorrelationFunction`
2. Using Fourier-Transformation as in the description in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Autocorrelation.html

In the following code I am comparing the two possibilities and would like to ask why the results are not exactly the same.

```
data = << "http://pastebin.com/raw/HDFCKW4M";

fps = 60 (* data frequency *);

time = Table[t/fps, {t, 1, Length[data]}] // N;
```

---

```
(* Method 1 *)

nautocorrelation = Length[data] - 1;
autocorrelation = CorrelationFunction[data, {nautocorrelation}];
modAutocorrelation = Abs[autocorrelation];

ListLogPlot[Transpose[{time, modAutocorrelation}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0.0001, All}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Amplitude", ""}, {"t (sec)", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Plain, FontSize -> 20}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

```
(* Method 2 *)

fData = Abs[Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]]^2;
ifData = InverseFourier[fData, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
modAutocorrelation = Abs[Re[ifData/ifData[[1]]]];

ListLogPlot[Transpose[{time, modAutocorrelation}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0.0001, All}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Amplitude", ""}, {"t (sec)", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Plain, FontSize -> 20}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Answer from Wolfram Technical Support**

As I understand, you are trying to match correlation functions from two of its definitions:

1. Statistical definition of autocorrelation function, which is what is the algorithmic basis for the function CorrelationFunction.
2. The signal processing definition of Auto correlation which you can derive from the Fourier Transform.

Since the algorithms are different in different definition, I wouldn't be surprised if the answers are different. Also, the FourierTransform definition gives a qualitative definition to obtain the peaks, which is indeed the case here.

HMMM not a very scientific explanation.